# UISplitView with UINavigaionController detailView

Tags: iphone, ios4

I see there is UINavigationController as masterView in UISplitView.And the detailView has a UIToolBar at most but isn't base on UINavigationController.
So I would like to make the detailview base on UINavigaionController then I can pushViewController to show other controllers.
Can somebody show me how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a UINavigaionController in your detail view class. Then, create the view by UINavigaionController and add to your detial view class.

Comment: Is that mean I create a UINavigationController on the detailview in front?

Comment: Yes. You can even add a UINavigationController in the master view. Just depends on your need.